# SecurityError when Export map to PNG

Tags: openlayers

I try to export my map to picture with the same method like [this example of OpenLayers 3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/export-map.html?q=png).

The problem is whith few baselayers, the function doesn't work and firebug say :

[image]

What can I dos for resolve this problem ?

Comment: Its CORS-related (http://enable-cors.org/). The Source is extern? Try to set `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` on your layer source or you could use a local proxy if the extern server doesnt support this Header (if the layer will not show up, then you know).

Comment: Where can I set `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` ? If I set this on the declaration of my layer, it doesn't work. I'm on a local server and I call tiles from an extern source.

Comment: In the layer SOURCE - like http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html.
Check Browser Console if you can find Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*".  Network Analysis->Click a File received ->Header

Comment: addition: If you cant set the "overall server configuration"  just add in the .htaccess 

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: If I add `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` to my layer, tiles don't load in my map, all is white ...

Comment: Since the last comment, I use now a personal basemap and the method  new ol.layer.Tile, so I don't have the crossOrigin option.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post REST endpoints of baselayers? In this way someone might have a look and be able to re-produce bug at our end.

Comment: try the addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/ and test it again!

Comment: What's REST endpoints of baselayers? I try the add-on but it's not resolved problem